# Запрос на поиск по столбцам

Tags: php, mysql

Сейчас выводит поиск только по `user_name`, как сделать или `user_lastname` или `user_salary`?

```
$resultSet = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name LIKE '$search%'");
```

Answer (score 1):

Меняем WHERE (т.е. где)

```
SELECT * 
   FROM users 
   WHERE user_lastname LIKE '$search%'
SELECT * 
   FROM users 
   WHERE user_salary LIKE '$search%'
```

Для сортировки добавляем в конце ORDER BY ...

Если нужен поиск сразу по нескольким колонками пишем так

```
SELECT * 
   FROM users 
   WHERE 
    user_salary LIKE '$search%' OR 
    user_lastname LIKE '$search%'
```

Comment: благодарствую)))